# Move interactive markers using topics

Tags: rviz, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

Is there a way to move interactive markers from rviz, but outside rviz? Like publishing in a topic or something like this? I want the interactive marker to follow the hand of the user (published as a tf frame) in specific cases (when they press a button).

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260901/move-interactive-markers-using-topics/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about using a TF frame specifically, but you could take a look at the [moveit_joystick](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/ros_visualization/joystick.html) infrastructure that was added some time ago.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2017-05-14**:
Yes that will work! I will investigate the joystick controller. Here is the file if someone else needs:
http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_ros_visualization/html/moveitjoy__module_8py_source.html

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-15**:
It is also included in any recent MoveIt package.